# Retrieving posts by id

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, wordpress, http

I am receiving a JSON object from WordPress which looks like this

```
{
        "ID": 4164,
        "title": "24 Horas Non-Stop con Marco Carola",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "post",
        "author": {
            "ID": 11,
            "username": "VIlma Quiros",
            "registered": "2015-04-16T07:04:04+00:00",
            "meta": {
                "links": {
                    "self": "http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/users/11",
                    "archives": "http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/users/11/posts"
                }
            }
        },
        "content": "<p class=\"p2\"><a href=
```

here is my service

```
.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http, $q) {
  return {

    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      var posts = [];
      $http.get('http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts')
        .success(function(result) {
          $scope.posts = result;
        })
    },

    getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/postId';
      return $http.get(url);
    }

});
```

and here the controller

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, FreshlyPressed) {

  $scope.posts = [];

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();

});
```

and here is what I want:

in this view I display only the title and the date of the posts, this is the main view

```
  <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
    <p>{{:: post.date | date}}</p>
  </a>
```

when you click in that title you should be redirected to the entired post which is here, in the secondary view

```
  <div class="item item-text-wrap item-image padding">
    <div class="special-font" ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
  </div>
```

the routes

```
//the route for the main view

.state('tabs.news', {
    url: '/news',
    views: {
      'tab-news': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-news.html',
        controller: 'NewsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

//the route for the second view where you will see the entire post

.state('tabs.post-detail', {
  url: '/news/:postId',
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post-detail.html',
      controller: 'PostDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I get this error

`GET http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/postId 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Luke look at the route and the code. Should be ```urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/{{post.ID}}``` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to change this function like this

```
  getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/'+ postId;
      return $http.get(url);
```

as per you code postId is parameter that you want to replace in string than you should append value in string as in code

you need to call method like

```
   FreshlyPressed.getPostById(1);//1 is postid value
```

Comment: I am getting ```GET http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/undefined 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Where do you call `getPostById`?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer - than you need to pass postId value when you are calling function

Comment: as @RadonirinaMaminiaina mentioned, I just realized that when I call getPostById I wasn't passing the parameter, sorry, and thanks :)